# get remote rsync PID?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I am making an open source `rsync` manager and need to be able to kill client rsync process from server side.

Now, 2 clients are `rsync`ing files from server to clinet, and clients fire the `rsync` command to server and authenticated via ssh keys.

clinet-1 and client-2 both:

```
rsync -zav root@server:/home/aaa .
```

server:

```
ps aux | grep rsync

root      6117  8.9  0.7  87524 60604 ?        Ds   00:23   0:26 rsync --server --sender -vlogDtprz . /home/aaa
root      6339  8.6  0.6  87524 58792 ?        Ds   00:23   0:25 rsync --server --sender -vlogDtprz . /home/aaa
```

The problem is I need to know which pid corresponding to these individual client rsync command. In order to be able to kill them, anyone can point some directions?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write a script in the server (`/usr/bin/run_rsync`):

```
#!/bin/bash

client_ip=$1
client_id=$2
client_path=$3
rsync_script=~/rsync_CID$client_id
echo "rsync -zav /home/aaa root@$client_ip:$client_path" > $rsync_script
sh $rsync_script
rm $rsync_script
```

Then use this script from clients (`ssh root@server run_rsync <IP> <ID> $(pwd)`). And when you want to kill a client, at the server (given `$client_id`):

```
pstree $(pgrep CID$client_id) -ap | sed -n 's/.*rsync,\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

should give you the PID of rsync this client is using.

Comment: thanks for the answer, one question, if $client_ip is behind NAT, anyway to do it? I am now thinking doing some authentication at authorized_keys, trying to inject client_id into arguments.

Comment: It should be possible with port forwarding and using a different port number for each client (see the rsync `--port` option). Perhaps you can even use these port numbers to grep the PID of the client you are interested in (without using a wrapper as above).